# Have to mount the "data" partition every time

Tags: mount, hard-drive, automount

At my laptop I have one HDD with 2 partitions (OS and DATA).
Each time Ubuntu starts I have to mount it firstly so that I have access to it.
I want it to be automatically mounted.
How can I do that? And why it isn't by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automount NTFS partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by editing your */etc/fstab* file.

Excerpt from [SOURCE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab):

> **A root filesystem:**
>
> ```
> UUID=30fcb748-ad1e-4228-af2f-951e8e7b56df / ext3 defaults,errors=remount-ro,noatime 0 1
> ```
>
> **A non-root file system, ext2:**
>
> ```
> /dev/sdb1 /media/disk2 ext2 defaults 0 2
> ```
>
> **fat16 and fat32**
>
> ```
> /dev/hda2 /media/data1 vfat defaults,user,exec,uid=1000,gid=100,umask=000 0 0
>
> /dev/sdb1 /media/data2 vfat defaults,user,dmask=027,fmask=137 0 0
> ```
>
> **ntfs**
>
> This example is perfect for a Windows partition.
>
> ```
> /dev/hda2 /media/windows ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0
> ```

Comment: Ok, I did that and the partition is mounted automatically. The only problem is that it shows up at the launcher and at desktop. But I don't want it to be like that. Can't this partition be like an extra hdd that does not show up at the launcher and is mounted automatically? Thank you.

Comment: In order for that to happen, please make the mount point directories in `/mnt` (e.g., `/mnt/Data_Partition/`. Items in `/media` will show up on the desktop and launcher.

Comment: I made a dir at mnt folder via sudo mkdir /mnt/DATA/ and then used that "/mnt/DATA/" as a mount point. In fact I have added this line: /dev/sda5 /mnt/DATA/ ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0 and the partition doesn't show up at the computer. What is wrong?

Comment: @Chris Although the partition doesn't show up in the desktop/launcher, it is mounted. Just try browsing via your file manager to `/mnt/DATA/`. You could bookmark those locations in your file manager so that  you can access them easily. That's the way you add it, if you don't want it shown in the launcher/desktop.

Comment: I wanted it to be appeared as in windows, where it is always mounted and shows up in the computer. Isn't there any way to achieve that?

Comment: I don't know if there is a solution to put it in the "Computer" section. But dragging and dropping a folder to the sidebar in Nautilus (your file-manager, equivalent to windows explorer) will bookmark the location for easy access.