# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. What is the best and most reliable method to mount a NTFS partition?

Tags: ntfs, automount

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)

... and having full access on it plus auto mount option on Ubuntu startup?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the disc to `/etc/fstab`. Your create a backup and can edit the file with these 2 lines:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.old
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Example:

This assumes `sda3` is your `ntfs` partition and it should be mounted into `/media/windows/`

```
/dev/sda3   /media/windows  ntfs    defaults    0   0
```

So change `sda3` to your partitionname and the `windows` directory name to something you like better. You can use fdisk to see what ntfs is named in Ubuntu:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Comment: Thanks for info Rinzwind but I just found a good post that explained it how to do it with fstab very well. Is here http://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions

Answer (score 1):

To mount the drives without having to reboot all you've to do is:

```
sudo mount -a
```