# Clementine Player Problem Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: clementine

I recently installed clementine on my Ubuntu 11.10 box. It was fine at first use. But when i used it this morning, all my playlist were there but it is not playing a song. It's like it keeps looking for the file forever. I did not move the files anywhere. Same thing happened with rythmnbox. help, please?

Comment: Please add some information on your system setup. There will be no drive `D:` in Ubuntu. To automount Windows partitions in Ubuntu [see this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/46589/3940).

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly are these files?  Make sure that the disk with the music is mounted.  I did this once when I didn't mount my windows drive, but all my music was on it.

Comment: all my music folders are stored in D. i am very particular the way i sort my music. i did not make any changes to any folders or mp3 files."Make sure that the disk with the music is mounted. I did this once when I didn't mount my windows drive, but all my music was on it." so you mean, i have to open my D:\ folder first before I load the rythmnbox. Do i have to do it every time? It will not automatically detect the folders?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to open D:/ first.  If you want to have it automatically mount on startup, you'll need to find out where D is stored.  Assuming it's on sda3, you'll want to follow the directions at http://www.howtogeek.com/60817/how-to-auto-mount-partitions-at-linux-startup-the-easy-way/