# All partitions disappeared after a power outage

Tags: mount

After a power outage, my partitions won't appear anymore on my Ubuntu 12.04 but everything is fine on Windows. All are NTFS partitions on 2 different hard drives and I can see them typing `sudo fdisk -l`.

It's certainly a classical problem but I'm new here... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Boot to windows, scan your hard drives with the windows disk scan utility.
2. Restart, to windows again.
3. Shut down, power off the machine, remove the plug from the power socket. (basically recommended, but not required)
4. Boot in ubuntu and enjoy!

If problems persist, please check the disk using ubuntu's "disk utility", see if there is a problem reported with SMART monitor.

Comment: The "disk utility" was not in the "system settings" so I didn't it existed. So I managed to mount again my partitions after I killed the processus (sudo killall udisks). The last problem is that the partitions won't automount like before when the system starts. I guess it's an easy question too..

Comment: Ok I found how to automount, problem solved. http://askubuntu.com/a/46589/75189