# How to get ubuntu to recognize my 2nd laptop HDD on boot

Tags: hard-drive, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)

In my laptop running 12.04 I have a 2nd hard disk in via an HDD caddy at /dev/sdb3.  Since my main drive is a smaller SSD, this large hard drive is where I have Dropbox syncing too.

The problem is that my OS does not see that hard disk on boot, therefore if I set dropbox to run on startup it fails with all sorts of scary errors. To get my HDD recognized, I have to open nautlilus and navigate to it.  After doing this once I can start dropbox and other services that use that disk and everything runs fine.

I assume that this has to do with the fact that my hard disk is in the slot the dvd drive normally is. I really would like to stop doing this dance.  Is there way to either configure ubuntu, or even to just script this sequence of events so i can stop doing this manually?