# Problems mounting the NTFS partition.

Tags: partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)

I'm a linux noob so you're going to have to talk noobish to me to understand...

I just installed the newest version of ubuntu on my computer and I am having some problems mounting my NTFS drive. On boot it asks me to skip the mounting process or do it manually. I'm not sure what to do. When I do try to mount, I get this error: `Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with: mount: only root can mount /dev/sda2 on /media/286452716452422C –` I got the NTFS mounting tool and it doesn't seem to work right... Any ideas would be most helpful.

Comment: i guess sda2 is owned by root , try mounting it via `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Go to the dash and type "Terminal". Run it and type:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```

This will prompt you to enter your administrator password. Enter it.

This will install a program, that as the name goes, configures you ntfs partitions
in you drive.

In the following screenshot, configure your drive as I put it there

[image: The program to configure the drive]

Tick dev/sda2 and rename it to "/media/286452716452422C"

finally click auto configure.

Let me know if it works

Comment: I tried it and I got this. Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: only root can mount /dev/sda2 on /media/286452716452422C

Comment: How do I find the drive? I tried looking for it but I wasn't sure if it was right or not. When I tried mounting it I got the same error message.

Comment: Two folders with a bunch of numbers and dell utility

Comment: I did. I have the same problem... Not sure whats going on. You were right about the drive though.

Comment: It did and I did everything you said but It didn't do anything.

Comment: Didn't work either... No idea man. Maybe this computer just sucks.

Comment: @Cameron - Have you tried `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`

Comment: When I typed that in terminal I got this                     message.Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is hibernated. Please resume and shutdown Windows
properly, or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option, or
mount the volume read-write with the 'remove_hiberfile' mount option.
For example type on the command line

Comment: I also did what cgubuntu said as well. Nothing...

Comment: @Cameron I added a new solution