# Apache 'You don't have permission to access / on this server'

Tags: dual-boot, apache2, www

I just install apache2 on ubuntu,the default www directory is /var/www/ ,I use ln to link it to '/media/Software/Program Files/wamp/www/' at the windows directory,but the apache shows  'You don't have permission to access / on this server',Then I use 'sudo chmod -R 777  /media/Software/Program\ Files/wamp/www/' to set the permission,but it didn't work,and nothing changed when I saw the permission in the preporties of the '.../wamp/www' folder.So I want to know How can I change the www directory to '.../wamp/www' as I also need to access this diretory in windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things around.

One is whether Apache is allowed to follow symlinks. Is you link a symlink via ln -s? It is the recommended way but it might be a security issue in some servers and it is disabled many times.

See https://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks for more info on that topic but esentially you need `AllowOverride None` as here:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Other topic is the permissions.

### Windows Partition

As it is a Windows directory (it seems so) the best option will be to follow this guide http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604251:

Essentially it recommends you to edit the `/etc/fstab`
The line should be like this one:

```
/dev/sdb5 /media/Software ntfs-3g defaults, ..., umask=227 0 0
```

The interesting part is the umask. I will recommend to put the last digit as 6 or 7 for allowing Apache to access.

The recommended way is to use UUID. The steps are:

0) Make a backup of fstab (just in case ;))

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
```

1) Get the UUID of your hard-drive:

```
sudo blkid
```

2) Add the line in fstab

It should be something like this:

```
UUID=$you_uuid  /media/Software  ntfs-3g  defaults,user,auto,utf8
```

I have added auto so that it auto mounts. If you don't want that use noauto instead.

This will give it full permission. If you prefer different permissions use `dmask=000,fmask=111` as options. Instead of the it uses different numbers than `chmod`. If you want you can add also `uid=100,gid=100` with the wanted another uid or gid.

References:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab
[How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=283131

### Linux/Unix Partition (if not using Windows partitions)

If it is not a Windows partition the permissions should be in the standard linux way.

The best option is to change the permission of that directory. I will do it in this way:

```
chgrp -R www-data /media/Software/Program Files/wamp/www/
```

Also you will need read permission (maybe write) for that directory. It is done in this way:

```
chmod g+r /media/Software/Program Files/wamp/www
```

For also adding write:

```
chmod g+rw /media/Software/Program Files/wamp/www
```

But again that won't work if the partition is a NTFS partition because Windows do not store permission in the disk in this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.for the first topic,I did use ln -s,and thank you for your reminding me about the security issue.I use the symlink just want to try if the permission works。The main problem is the second topic,it's a NTFS partition,so,do you mean that I should edit the /etc/fstab ?I just think the NTFS partiton is hard to deal with in the linux but I need to use that in windows.

Comment: Yes, you should edit it in `/etc/fstab` NTFS does not save information about permissions. You need to say which permissions to use on that partition. I'm updating the answer with some help in this topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I have solved that problem by edit the fstab.

Comment: Perfect, I am happy to help. If you used my instructions for editing the fstab you could accept my answer so that incoming users don't need to read the comments ;)

Comment: OK,I just didn't know that,I am new here.

Comment: I'm new too but: Welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a default Apache install, you should update the DocumentRoot directive inside /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default and have this it point to /media/Software/Program\ Files/wamp/www/

DocumentRoot   /media/Software/Program\ Files/wamp/www

Further infos can be found here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html

Comment: I think it will turns out the same as I did,I have done that before,the main problem is that the apache has no permission to access the /media/Software/Program\ Files/wamp/www

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was none of the above but something much simpler.

I had two Apache2 virtual hosts competing for the same domain name in the ServerAlias line.

In one virtual host file, I had

ServerAlias mysubhost.myhost.me

but in the other virtual host file I had a wildcard entry:

ServerAlias *.myhost.me

This caused a conflict in Apache 2. Removing the wildcard entry (with the *) solved the problem for me.

(Taken from (K)Ubuntuguide at http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Dynamic_dns#Troubleshooting .)