# After renaming directory, getting "Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server."

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, lamp

I'm getting the error cited in the title when I try to browse locally to index.html (or any other file in the html-root directory I've specified, and I can't figure out why.  What follows is the timeline leading up to my posting of this request for help/suggestions:

Yesterday, I did a brand-new install of LAMP on a stable-for-over-two-years Ubuntu 14.04 machine.  I set everything up as specified here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

The first thing I did after the install was to reconfigure apache2 to have a different html-root inside my home dir: /home/user/Websites/MySite/.  I created an index.html in MySite and was able to browse to it using "http colon-backwhack-backwhack localhost" in Firefox.  I then created a test.php file, to which I could also browse (http colon-backwhack-backwhack localhost/test.php) successfully.

This morning, I renamed MySite to MyNewSite.  I created new apache2 config files (following the directions at the link specified above), just as I had yesterday.  I've quadruple-checked that I don't have any typos in the config files.  I've tried all the suggestions, or determined them not to be relevant, at the following locations:
[Apache 'You don't have permission to access / on this server'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221634/apache-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

(can't post 4 additional links because I don't have enough reputation points)

I don't know why it worked perfectly yesterday and changing it to point at a new directory hosed it.  Specifically, why is apache2 trying to access anything in the root (/)?  And what do I need to look at/change to get it working again?

Comment: You did reload the apache confs?  sudo apache2ctl graceful, it could be trying to look in the old location, and the files aren't there anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Apache user does not have permission to read the specified file in that directory. Be sure that www-data, which is the default user on Ubuntu, can read there.

More information here:

https://serverfault.com/a/357109

Answer (score 0):

By combining carnau's suggestion, below, and Progrock's suggestion, above, I got it working!

As carnau suggested: I studied up on permissions and discovered that the permissions for the folders in question were not quite right.  I was both the user-owner and the group-owner of the objects.  I fixed that, making sure that www-data was the group-owner and that the www-data group had r-x permissions.  All the objects are now set to "755" permissions.

Unfortunately, when I tried the browse to index.html, after fixing the permissions issue, I still got the same error.

Then I tried Progrock's solution.  I didn't think it would change anything because I HAD reloaded apache2 after making changes to the config files, using `sudo service apache2 reload`.  Apparently, `sudo apache2ctl graceful` does something different because after issuing that command, everything works fine now.

Thank you to carnau and Progrock!