# after a reboot banshee cant find music files (stored on D: partition with ntfs format)

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, music, banshee

i recently made the step towards ubuntu 13.04 and while using banshee as well as with rythmbox every time i restart my machine she cant find my music files.
(big ¨!" in front of the songs) i have to delete my library and import it again and its just fine again.. till i restart.

i have my music stored onto a seperate partition with ntfs format.
(i put it there while using win7)

any ideas?

Comment: By default Ubuntu does not mount NTFS partitions on startup. You can try mounting your Windows partition before opening Banshee or you can try the answer of [How to automount NTFS partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions). The best solution, though, is creating a FAT32 partition to store your music files, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the D: partition is not automatically mounted by Ubuntu, so Banshee can't find it.

1. Run the command `sudo apt-get install nfts-config`
2. Search for NFTS Configuration Tool in your Dash
3. Open it and select the D: partition, then configure it to mount automatically.

You may need to reboot your computer, but Banshee should work after that.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D 
it works now like a charm :3 awesome for the quick reply :)
very helpfull (^_^)

Comment: sorry i cant yet upvote, but else you had my +1 :D