# Access Windows directories with dual boot

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-7, drive

I'm using both windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10 on the same computer.

Normally on Ubuntu I can access anything on drive Q,so I usually use that drive as a share platform between the two OS because I switch between the two very frequently.

Is there a way that I could access all of the others drives of windows on Ubuntu?

If it's possible to do it in both ways it'd be even better! Thanks

Here's a screenshot of the current devices listed on Nautilus.

[image: Lenovo is drive Q]

Comment: Hello kwan. Welcome to AskUbuntu. Do you mind telling us how many drives are we talking about? Drive Q sounds like you have a lot of them but "Windows Drive C" can easily be accesed by Ubuntu by choosing the proper device on the left bar of Nautilus. The same should work for the other devices but if you are trying to access Ubuntu's partitions from Windows please let us know by rewording your question. There are good possibilities to do both tasks but let's face a situation at once. Thank you.

Comment: There are only 2 main drives actually! I really don't know why its named Q. Here's a picture of what i have on the left of Nautilus: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xfszs1q5hbfcpny/Screenshot%20from%202013-07-17%2002%3A02%3A46.png
"Lenovo..." being drive Q equivalent on Windows

Answer (score 2):

Linux handles drives in a different manner to Windows.

In Windows, every partition and volume is assigned a separate drive letter, like C: for partition where the OS is installed, D: for a DVD drive, and so on for removable USB devices and the like.

Since Windows XP, there has been the option to mount an NTFS partition onto another already existing format. It is this kind of system that Ubuntu and other Linux distros use. The main filesystem is mount at '/', and other volumes are mounted at some point within the filesystem, typically within the '/mnt/' directory. When you click on a drive that isn't already mounted in the launcher or Nautilus, Ubuntu auto-mounts it to a folder in the '/mount/' directory. If you can see the partition you want to access in Nautilus, you should be able to just double-click it and it should auto-mount and display its files.

If that works, great! You're done. If not, it can be a little more complicated. Each volume is automatically assigned a reference file in the '/dev/' directory. For hard disks, these are typically of the form '/dev/sdX' or '/dev/sdxY', where X is a letter indicating the disk, starting from 'a', and Y is a number indicating the partition, starting from '1'. to manually mount a partition, do the following:

1. Open a terminal (with CTRL + ALT + T or from the launcher)
2. Create a directory for the volume to be mounted to in the '/mnt/' directory (e.g. `sudo mkdir /mnt/folder`)
3. Use the `mount` command to first check if the drive you're trying to mount is already mounted. If so, do `sudo umount /dev/sdXY`
4. Once unmounted, do `sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/folder`
5. To open the mounted volume in Nautilus, do `nautilus /mnt/folder &`. You can close the terminal now.

If anything is unclear or confusing, just leave a comment.

Comment: Sorry I lost you at that "When you click on a drive that isn't already mounted in the launcher or Nautilus" point. How can i click on something if I can't see it on Nautilus? Really sorry I know I sound like a real ubuntu noob. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can mount all NTFS Windows disks without any problems. You can mount them on the start via fstab or you can let ubuntu to detect them automatically and mount on demand. You can follow this guide: [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)