# Why are partitons not automatically mounting?

Tags: partitioning

After installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, the Windows 7 partition and an extra backup partition are no longer mounting automatically as they used to do in 10.04.2 LTS.

I have an ATA HardDisk.

What could be the problem? Any insights will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can make them to mount automatically!! You have edit `/etc/fstab` and make an entry to to file in order to make them mount automatically!!

Comment: Saurav, what entry do I make?

Comment: Hi, please read this article first. http://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions

Comment: @DarkWarrior: Check my answer.. Reply for further assistance..

Answer (score 1):

You have to enter your partition information to `/etc/fstab` file. Then your disk will be mounted automatically!

Just go for following step:

- First take back up of `/etc/fstab`

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup
  ```
- Execute following command to get your partition **UUID** information that will help you to configure `/etc/fstab` file.

  ```
  sudo blkid
  ```

  Search for your partition's **UUID** which you want to mount automaticall. Your HDD partitions shouls be displayed like:

  ```
  /dev/sda1: LABEL="Backup" UUID="00A0CE7EA0CE7A24" TYPE="ntfs"
  /dev/sda5: LABEL="40GBTWO" UUID="00A0CE7EA0CE7A24" TYPE="ntfs" 
  /dev/sda6: UUID="7550252c-3da7-4cd9-8da3-71e9ba38e74a" TYPE="ext4" 
  /dev/sda7: UUID="088fd084-a011-4896-aa93-c0caaad60620" TYPE="swap" 
  /dev/sdb1: LABEL="SaurK" UUID="0DB6254A58CEF6F7" TYPE="ntfs"
  ```

  and so on. It is just an example but format will be same.
- Now copy the **UUID** of the partitions which you want to insert in `/etc/fstab` file.
- Now open `/etc/fstab` file and insert entry for your HDD partitions on the last line of `/etc/fstab` file. Take help from previous entry, for format etc:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/fstab
  ```

  When opened your entry would be like this:

  ```
  UUID=<your_UUID_for_Disk_partitions> /media/<location_where_you_want_to_mount>             ntfs    errors=remount-ro 0
  ```

  Just an example:

  ```
  UUID=00A0CE7EA0CE7A24 /media/Backup               ntfs    errors=remount-ro 0
  ```

  you may have to replace `ntfs` to `ext4` or `fat32` according to the `file system` of your partition. It displays in `blkid` output.
- Now create location where to mount your disk partitions. Create a folder for each partitions to mount. ((note: a directory may be already created, if so ignore this step.) For example:

  ```
  sudo mkdir /media/Backup
  ```
- Then execute this command once finished:

  ```
  sudo mount -a
  ```

You can refer this link for further help: [Auto mounting with /etc/fstab](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1635576)
Hope it works for you..

Comment: Thanks but this solved my problem: installing pysdm

Comment: That's good!! New packages have come to market.. :) I told you the ancient traditional way.. You would be scared.. :D