# ubuntu how to mount an ntfs with me as owner

Tags: 12.04

so far:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0000,dmask=0000 /dev/sdc1 /media/BB
```

works fine, every permission is set to read and write, now all i need is for the owner not to be "root"

what can i do to mount the ntfs with me as owner?

is there any modification i can to the above command?

like user="me" ? or what? ive searched far and wide and cant find so much things

mount help is not verry helpful

```
mount --help
Usage: mount -V                 : print version
       mount -h                 : print this help
       mount                    : list mounted filesystems
       mount -l                 : idem, including volume labels
So far the informational part. Next the mounting.
The command is `mount [-t fstype] something somewhere'.
Details found in /etc/fstab may be omitted.
       mount -a [-t|-O] ...     : mount all stuff from /etc/fstab
       mount device             : mount device at the known place
       mount directory          : mount known device here
       mount -t type dev dir    : ordinary mount command
Note that one does not really mount a device, one mounts
a filesystem (of the given type) found on the device.
One can also mount an already visible directory tree elsewhere:
   mount --bind olddir newdir
or move a subtree:
       mount --move olddir newdir
One can change the type of mount containing the directory dir:
       mount --make-shared dir
       mount --make-slave dir
       mount --make-private dir
       mount --make-unbindable dir
One can change the type of all the mounts in a mount subtree
containing the directory dir:
       mount --make-rshared dir
       mount --make-rslave dir
       mount --make-rprivate dir
       mount --make-runbindable dir
A device can be given by name, say /dev/hda1 or /dev/cdrom,
or by label, using  -L label  or by uuid, using  -U uuid .
Other options: [-nfFrsvw] [-o options] [-p passwdfd].
For many more details, say  man 8 mount .
```

Answer (score 0):

A. `sudo mkdir /media/ntfsPartition` - this will create a folder in your **media** directory, you can add any name you want;

B. `sudo blkid` - find the UUID of the ntfs partition you want to mount;

C. `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` - add a new line with your ntfs partition you wish to mount by writing a new line on bottom (ex: should look like this)

```
#ntfs_partition
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /media/ntfsPartition ntfs defauls,uid=1000,gid=1000,noatime 0 0
```

(before point D, check if the uid and gid is 1000 by typing in terminal `id`)

D. Save the file;

E. `sudo mount -a` - this will mount your ntfs partition;

F. Done

*Testing and using my ntfs partitions in this way on Ubuntu 14.04.

For older versions, check this - [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-prevent-automount-of-ntfs-partitions-on-startup)

Comment: Yep! The option "user" only applies to mounts that are listed in /etc/fstab. This is the file that "preloads" the valid mount points including /. With the entry in /etc/fstab, it will "preload" the user option. Then, when the `mount` command it used, if the user option exists in /etc/fstab, then it will allow the mount.

Comment: Of course, for one-time mounts, you should be able to use the command `sudo mount -t ntfs -o defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,noatime /dev/sdX /media/ntfsPartition` (where /dev/sdX is the device name of the partition that can be found via `gdisk -l`/`fdisk -l`) or even `mount -t ntfs -o defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,noatime /dev/disk/by-uuid/[uuid from above] /media/ntfsPartition`