# mount point for windows after setting ubuntu to `/`

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, mount, ntfs

I changed partitions on my machine so that win7 (NFTS) has 100GB, 16GB for swap, and 380GB for EXT4 where I will install Linux.  I set the mount point for for linux to `/`.
What should I set the win7 partition to ?
my options appear to be `/dos` or `/windows`.

Comment: You don't need to set one now. You can set mounting later, after installing: http://askubuntu.com/q/46588/158442

Comment: Do you really want to always have the windows partition mounted at boot / all the time? Usually the file browser (nautilus, thunar, etc) has a one-click-mount listing somewhere, probably to /media/something

Answer (score 2):

Either of these will work perfectly fine. The differences only affect the path to the folders and files in that partition.

As an example, if you wanted to open a file on the Windows partition called `file.txt`, with `/dos` as the mountpoint the path would be `/dos/file.txt`. Using `/windows` would make the path `/windows/file.txt`.