# unable to login user ubuntu user account after activating the automount partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, login

I had a great problem with auto mounting partition. Every time after start up the pc I had to do manually mount all the drives. so I searched for a solution then I found this...

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/07/mount-partitions-automatically-ubuntu-14-04/

I do as it showed me to do. then I give a reboot. but now I am not able to log in my account. when I giving password, it blinks and ask to give password again. Now I am using the guest account.

Is there any way to **system restore** or like something else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a system restore and it's called a [system back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) but if you didn't make one before you started, you obviously don't have one...

So the *easiest* to do for you now, is to boot from a LiveCD (the CD you installed it with) and choose "try Ubuntu".  Then make a full file back-up, (get your file data off the machine onto another medium) and re-install...

Afterwards, to auto-mount your drives, have a look here: [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions) instead (it works for any file system)

There is also the *hard* way of repairing this and that is to look for any changes in the `fstab` and figuring out what changed.  As you have no point of reference (do you have a back-up of `fstab`?) this is going to be difficult for you, so I would advise against it.

**Note:** look at Ask Ubuntu first; you're not the first one that bricks his system from reading from this guy's blog. (NVidia drivers that make your system crash, easily auto-mount drives, ... )