# Share dropbox folder between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, dropbox

I have `Windows 8` and `Ubuntu` installed on the same HDD. I have created separate NTFS partition for Dropbox and trying to share Dropbox folder for both OS. Everything works fine with from Windows side, but I have problem when Ubuntu with Dropbox starts up. During this procedure I have message:

```
Your Dropbox folder has been moved or deleted from its original location. Dropbox will not work properly until you move it back. It used to be located at: /media/blabla/Dropbox/Dropbox

    To move it back, click "Exit" below, move the Dropbox folder back to its original location, and launch Dropbox again.

    This computer was previously linked to blabla@gmail.com's account.

    If you'd like to link to an account again to download and restore your Dropbox from the web version, click "Relink".
```

Path to mounted dropbox folder is `/media/blabla/Dropbox/Dropbox`

When I explore dropbox folder in file explorer - I see dropbox file.

When I do relink procedure Dropbox works file also till next Ubuntu restart.

How to solve restart problem?

UPD.

Looks like I found problem.  My Ubuntu not mounts NTFS folder with Dropbox content during startup. It mounts only when do browse to this partition from file explorer. Solution would be ask Ubuntu mount Dropbox partition automatically during startup. How to do that?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions

Answer (score 0):

You should log out completely, log in again and link that folder again (go to the Dropbox icon in the menu bar; go to settings -> in the second tab you can make a new link to your folder).
If this still does not work try reinstalling Dropbox. And make sure to delete the unused/left over folders.

This one solved (at least for my part) the problems.

Comment: Looks like I found problem.  My Ubuntu not mounts NTFS folder with Dropbox content during startup. It mounts only when do browse to this partition from file explorer. Solution would be ask Ubuntu mount Dropbox partition automatically during startup. How to do that?

Comment: don't you have installed the _Dropbox App_ from the website or the software center?