# Is 30 GB enough space for working with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside windows 7. I have 4 partitions on windows 7. I had a 73 GB partition which I could have used in it's entirety for installing ubuntu. Unfortunately, when I chose to install ubuntu alongside windows 7 it only took 30 GB of that partition and I didn't re-size it.

My question is - Will I be able to access windows partitions and install software on them if I wish to do so from my ubuntu login? Will 30 GB be sufficient to install all updates/packages/software? I plan to do some side dev projects on the machine.

Are these instructions safe for re-sizing the windows partition and assigning it to ubuntu - http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd or are there better instructions available?

Comment: here's the link to see how it should look like https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: @JoKeR Thanks. I have already installed 14.04 LTS. I was looking for a post installation increase in allocation of space. The link gives suggestions for increasing space during installation.

Comment: You mean how to resize partitions? check this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions

Comment: @JoKeR Yes, that helps, thanks. Unrelated - How easy is it to use windows/NTFS partitions in ubuntu to install software and work with them?

Comment: I use it with no issues...

Comment: Is there something specific I need to do for that or can I just use it like the native space?

Comment: I use it as basic storage... though you can configure it as the other partitions too by setting mods etc. depends on your needs. You can find lots of info similar to this http://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions about *ntfs* on askubuntu, just google it....