# How to automount ntfs internal hard drive as user

Tags: dual-boot, mount, permissions, 15.10

The title pretty much explains it. I am on windows and ubuntu dual boot. When I set automatic mount options on in the app disk, the system does not auto mount the drive. I need to click the drive to mount. When I set automatic mount options off and check mount at startup. It works but is mounted as root. As a result, I cannot put any file in trash.

Comment: What gui are you using to mount the drives? Have you looked at this question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions?rq=1

Comment: Unity. I did search on the internet. But those methods do not work

Answer (score 0):

I've organized this answer going what is good to best answer in my opinion. It's not a requirement to do all of them and user discretion is advised :)

**/etc/fstab approach**

The way I'd personally do it use `users` option. That way , a partition is available to all users - maybe I've car manual that my dad wants to read there with his account, maybe my mom also wants to open shared photo album using her account - whatever the reason may be. An example would be:

```
# MY WINDOWS PARTITION

UUID=4EBAAE53BAAE36FD /media/WINDOWS  ntfs noatime,nodiratime,users,rw 0 0
```

However, yes, that's a security hole. So next better option is this to use `uid=` flag. Each user on a *nix system has unique integer number attached to them (run `id` command to find out your numeric id, or look into `/etc/passwd` file and find your username ). So, the next entry for me would look like this:

# MY WINDOWS PARTITION

```
UUID=4EBAAE53BAAE36FD /media/WINDOWS  ntfs noatime,nodiratime,uid=1000,rw 0 0
```

**udisksctl approach**

`mount` command wants you to specify a lot of information - user, filesystem type. These pieces of info you might not know how to find. There is an easier alternative, `udisksctl`. It will mount a partition *as the user who runs it*. Here's how I'd run it if I want to mount my Windows partition on my second HDD:

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb2
```

And that easily can be turned into a function in `.bashrc` file (define at the top)

```
function mountWindows
{
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb2
}
```

Now you basically have a command for mounting Windows partition. If you place call to that function at the end of your `.bashrc` it will be running each time you spawn terminal window. Of course it's not exactly automation , but for someone like myself  who constantly has terminal window open - it's easiest automation method.

There's a small issue however - the call is made each time `bash` starts, meaning each time window is open. With a bit of editing we can include a check to whether or not the partition is already mounted or not.

```
function mountWindows
{
grep -q '/dev/sdb2' /proc/mounts
if [ $? -eq 0  ];then 
  echo ">>> Windows partition already mounted"; 
else udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb2
fi
}
```

Now, each time we spawn `bash` we quietly check if `/dev/sdb2` is in the `/proc/mounts` file (only stuff that's already mounted is in that file). If it's there, we just say so. If it's not, we'll run `udisksctl` command.