# the disk drive for /dos is not ready yet or not present

Tags: dual-boot, mount

I had Windows and Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my computer. My disk drives were mounted in Ubuntu. Only windows installation drive were mounted to /dos. But after re-installing windows, I had to recover Ubuntu boot and since then

> The disk drive for /dos is not ready yet or not present 
>   Continue to wait or press s to skip mounting or M for manual recovery

and every time I have to press "s" to enter ubuntu. I tried remounting but didnot work. On disk info application it showing "Device- /dev/sda2" . What should I do?

Edit:

`/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=99958f24-0ff1-4317-b73f-f3380a01675d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /dos was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=6A16052B1604FA39 /dos            ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# /home was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=5af218fd-721a-460c-8a55-f3cf06d6ac39 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /windows/entertainment was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=08E89C1BE89C0958 /windows/entertainment ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# /windows/personal was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=F4C02C8CC02C5760 /windows/personal ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# /windows/software was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=0E9CF5219CF503CD /windows/software ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=b3a60872-5000-40d7-9ee5-3e4d6e84f7c4 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=0C76B0D476B0C02E /dos ntfs defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0 0
```

-> This came entering "sudo lsblk"

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  99.9G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   100G  0 part /windows/software
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   200G  0 part /windows/personal
├─sda6   8:6    0   450G  0 part /windows/entertainment
├─sda7   8:7    0  27.7G  0 part /
├─sda8   8:8    0   5.7G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda9   8:9    0  47.7G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

and this came aftering "sudo blkid"

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="D484A83F84A82648" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="0C76B0D476B0C02E" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Software" UUID="0E9CF5219CF503CD" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Personal" UUID="F4C02C8CC02C5760" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Entertainment" UUID="08E89C1BE89C0958" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="99958f24-0ff1-4317-b73f-f3380a01675d" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="b3a60872-5000-40d7-9ee5-3e4d6e84f7c4" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda9: UUID="5af218fd-721a-460c-8a55-f3cf06d6ac39" TYPE="ext4"
```

N.B. - I tried editing /etc/fstab by reading [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions) . But still no good

Comment: What happens when you do `sudo update-grub`? Also, please edit the contents of `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/mtab` into your post.

Comment: I don't understand what you are telling me to edit in my post. But here is my /etc/fstab and /etc/mtab. Please suggest me something

Comment: please edit in the output of `sudo lsblk` and `sudo blkid` as well, thank you