# How to make shared partition on dual boot between Windows 10 & Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, sharing

I want to make dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 and have a shared partition between both OSes. I know that it should be with NTFS file system and I am going to make it the last partiotion, after all other partiotions are set.

Is all I have to do, just create the NTFS partiotion ? I red a tutorial where the OP creates a linux directorie and wants to  mount the ntfs partition to be there, he is searching the UUID of the partition and he tweaks some code in /etc/fstab file. But it seems this tutorials are a little bit older.

On other places I red that all you need to do is creat the partition and it will be visible in nautilus and in Windows.

I want to share files on this partition when I want, and not to automatically be shared between the OSes. Example I would have Windows drives `C:` for Windows `D:` for data and separate software(like games) and let's say `E:` which is going to be shared paritition with the Ubuntu and I would put data when I need it to be on both systems so I don't have to always upload and download the data I need to be shared. Same for Linux I would have /, /home and for example `/home/storage = E:` directorie which will be the shared partition.

If I have to do more, than just creating the partition. Please write the steps as simple as possible and explain. Thank you.

Comment: If you just want to save files to the shared partition, then all you have to do is create it. But be sure in Windows to turn off fast start up or its always on hibernation as it will keep all NTFS partitions mounted. And then any data from Linux is lost. Usually if an internal drive better to automatically mount with fstab so  it always is there in same place but not required.https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I don't have reputation to comment so..)

I had installed windows 8.1 on drive C:. I then installed ubuntu 15.10 on drive D:. Now, all the ntfs partition including C: is visible and accessible to Ubuntu but drive D: is no longer ntfs and hence not visible to windows. If this fits your needs, I will explain steps of doing so.