# Will I be able to play media files stored in Windows partition?

Tags: dual-boot, compatibility

Can I play video and audio files (like MP4 and WAV files that were made with Windows 10 or 7 and are located in a windows partition) in an Ubuntu video player that is located in its own Ubuntu partition, though both partition are located on the same hard-drive or maybe located on a separate hard-drive

In other words, will Ubuntu recognize and use files that are in a windows partition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automount NTFS partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)

Comment: This question may be duplicate, but I disagree with the close votes with that duplicate target

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Depending on your configuration, your windows partition will be auto-mounted or displayed as mountable on your file manager which in called Nautilus in default Ubuntu installation.

Make sure you did clean shut down your windows 10 completely, i.e. no Hibernation, so that your ntfs partitions are in clean state. Otherwise, You may not mount those Windows partition until you restarted to Windows and shutdown. Sometimes, calling `ntfsfix` from a terminal may help without rebooting to Windows, but ***You could lose data by doing so***.

mp4 and WAV files can be played by default Ubuntu audio, video players. However, You need to have necessary codecs installed for the players be able to play the files. One options is installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package.