# Windows 10 Dual Boot shared NTFS partition Read Only, Fast Shutdown Disabled

Tags: dual-boot, ntfs

This seems like a really common question here, but I think some things changed for it in Ubuntu 18.04...

So I started with a completely blank 1TB SSD yesterday, installed windows first, then created a 80 GB partition for ubuntu and a 16 GB Swap partition. Then went back into windows and filled the rest of the drive with an NTFS partition for shared file space between the two OSs. With the extra recovery / boot paritions windows makes this is what it looks like:

[image: Partition Schema]

Partition 4 is Windows C:\
Partition 6 is /
Partition 7 is Windows D:\ (shared data)

From the disk manager in ubuntu I can click the settings button and there are auto mount options that seem to work so I used those rather than editing fstab directly. The only problem is partition 7 is mounting as read only

[image: Mounting Options from Disk Manager]

[image: Data properties]

As far as I know the only potential problem is windows "Fast Start" feature, which I've done everything I can to disable so either there is another problem or somehow windows is doing its fast start anyways.

First I turned off fast-start from the power settings:[image: Fast Start Power Settings]

Then I followed other steps from [this guide](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html) to disable fast startup:

.bat file

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /V HiberbootEnabled /T REG_dWORD /D 0 /F
```

.reg file

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System]
"HiberbootEnabled"=-
```

Ideally switching from windows to linux would be as easy as using the restart button but I guess this makes use of fast-startup anyways so I tried using the shutdown button instead, and holding shift while using the shutdown button. None of these make the partition mount as read/write.

Some other things to note for the record:

- ntfs-3g is installed
- I saw a suggestion somewhere to set umask to 000 but after reading more about it this seems like it's not the "right" option? Maybe I'm wrong, but it seemed like there were warning flags when I read up on this from ... somewhere don't remember where

Comment: Most comments I have seen have said Disks default parameters are not the best. This is one option. https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions I also have seen these: `defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000,windows_names` You need windows_names to avoid use of invalid characters. Edit with `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and to make sure edit is valid this should just return with no message. `sudo mount -a`

Comment: @oldfred you mention umask=000. Isn't that bad? I could have sworn I saw warnings about that somewhere

Comment: I just copied an example & yes you are correct. umask=000 sets the permissions of files and folders to 777 or rwxrwxrwx. And wide open permissions is not recommended as execute is also allowed. umask=007 will grant users read/write permissions. If you want all users to have read/write you can add gid=46 which  is group=plugdev.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify /etc/fstab and change 'ntfs' to 'ntfs-3g'.

Remount all disks.

> ```
> sudo mount -a
> ```

Maybe it report you some nfts system error, you can try tu use :

> ```
> sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2
> ```

To mount and modify the parameters you can use Disk Manager, but in this case you will not be able to see the errors.