# Installing new SSD for storage shared among Ubuntu and Windows on dual boot PC

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I have a dual-boot PC which runs Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10, both of which are installed on the same SSD.

I would like to install a second SSD (Samsung 860 EVO SATA III 2.5" 1TB), for storing files. Ideally, I would like to create 3 partitions:

- One partition shared on both Ubuntu and Windows
- One partition only accessible on Ubuntu
- One partition only accessible on Windows

Moreover, I do not want to have to reinstall Ubuntu nor Windows.

What do I need to do to achieve this?

*My level: I have never changed the partitions of any HDD/SSD before (neither on Ubuntu nor Windows) and have no idea where to start.*

Comment: You still need Windows fast start up off. You need two NTFS partitions and one ext4 partition. You can use gparted, but you may need to run chkdsk from Windows on the NTFS partitions. I would be sure to use gpt partitioning and if ever installing Ubuntu on it, include a smaller ESP as first partition. Windows will not see ext4. You in fstab can set NTFS mount as read only, read/write or not read it at all.https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting/1013700#1013700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ubuntu can easily and reliably access files on an NTFS volume, but Windows cannot reliably access files on an ext4 or other Linux partition, why not just make one NTFS partition for data on the second drive? You would not need to reinstall either Windows or Ubuntu.

When you attach the second drive, use Windows Disk Management to prepare the new drive, then reboot into Ubuntu and set up the drive to be automatically mounted in Ubuntu. as *oldfred* [noted above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions).

You can even visit https://superuser.com and find out how to move your swap file, temp files, and page file to the second drive. That shifts some of the drive activity to the second drive and reduces Windows slowness some.

Comment: Ok. How do I make a NTFS partition ? Do I need to do it on Windows or Ubuntu, or does it just get created automatically? (I should mention that I haven't yet physically installed the SSD yet, so I don't even know what Ubuntu/Windows sees when I first install it)

Comment: Make in either Windows or Ubuntu.