# Dual Boot: Access windows files from ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, mount, filesystem, 19.04, windows-10

Windows 10, Ubuntu 19.04

I have mounted my Windows NTFS drive in ubuntu, heres the line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=7A828C80828C429D   /c  ntfs-3g uid=vale,gid=vale,rw,user,auto  0 0
```

When I try to open any files, e.g. pdf-files i get the following error popup:

```
There is no application installed for "symbolic link" files...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best to copy & paste a good example with correct parameters and edit to be your UUID & your mount point. https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions Also better to mount Windows partition as read only and create another NTFS for shared read/write use. Then no chace of accidentally modifing files in the main Windows install.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem mounting my Windows (C:) drive in Ubuntu 18.04.

The files I was attempting to open were in my Dropbox folder on my Windows partition. Dropbox allows you to store files in the cloud and sync on the fly.

This is done by making links to symbolic links. Apparently Ubuntu cannot open these links (or similar links from cloud services).

I fixed this by making sure all files I wanted were on my local machine. Hope this helps.