# Best way to mount HD's?

Tags: mount, fstab

I've been away from Linux for a while and am now a bit confused with mounting procedures.
By default, only the SSD with my root file system was mounted after installing **Ubuntu 20.04**.

When opening the default Nautilus file manager, I can easily mount other drives but those are not persistent mounts and come under /media/<user>/<drive>.
What I would ideally want (on a multi-user system) is that drives are mounted at startup on /media/<drive> using /etc/fstab (or whatever other way is better).

At the moment, I've added those drives and they're working but Nautilus is a mess and so is Nemo.
*Nautilus*: Under the "Devices" (bottom left) section, I can see the drives but when I click on them, an error comes up that the device isn't mounted. I can browse through to /mnt/<drive> and access the contents though.
*Nemo*: handles it a bit better, there they show mounted and I can click on them to used them. However, in the "My Computer" section, they also show up and give the not-mounted error.

Here's my custom /etc/fstab addition

```
/dev/sda1   /media/CT1000MX  ntfs   defaults    0   0
/dev/sdb1   /media/160G      ntfs   defaults    0   0   
/dev/sdd2   /media/DATA-2    ntfs   defaults    0   0
/dev/sde1   /media/WDBLUE1TB ntfs   defaults    0   0
/dev/sdf2   /media/DATA-1    ntfs   defaults    0   0
```

Except for my Windows drive, all others should be mounted automatically for all users without throwing all these errors in a file manager.
**Any suggestions** to clean this up would be greatly appreciated. If these are specific issues with these file managers, I'm certainly willing to replace them with another that doesn't have this behavior but I have a feeling I'm just doing something wrong.

[image]

Comment: Try "gnome-disks". It will let you edit mount options.

Comment: Do not use device like /dev/sda. I plug in a flash drive, it becomes sda and then sdb is sdc etc. Also drive order is based on how UEFI/BIOS find drives. That is not always consistent. That is now why UUID or labels are recommended for mounting. https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions Good explanation of options: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab Also seen these as better options for NTFS: `defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names` Window_names prevents the use of invalid windows characters:

Comment: Thanks. I think I got a bit confused because the disk entries got sticky in my file browser even after they were mounted on /media instead of /media/<user>/.
Also the UUID reminder was very helpful. I changed it all in /etc/fstab, now everything looks clean and works flawlessly. Cheers.