# ntfsusermap for triple boot

Tags: permissions, ntfs, user-management, ntfs-3g

I have a triple boot system: macOS, Windows (Fast Boot disabled), and Xubuntu. Beside the OS drive, there's a data drive formatted in NTFS.

I use `ntfsusermap` as mentioned in [osxfuse's NTFS-3G guide](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G) to write to the drive on macOS. However, I can't write normally under Xubuntu anymore. For example:

- `touch new_file` *does create* `new_file`, but it complains `setting times of 'new_file': Permission denied`.
- `rm new_file` complains `remove write-protected regular empty file 'new_file'`. `rm -f` works.

I think this `ntfsusermap` is the problem, I've never touched the permission on Windows. What can I do to fix or at least debug this?

Update: `getacl` on the drive gives me this:

```
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: dialout
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

And on any file, folder inside:

```
# file: xxx
# owner: 501
# group: dialout
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

Update 2: My `fstab` line, I just copy the line in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/46589/892000):

```
UUID=xxxx /media/DATA ntfs rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0
```

Comment: Permissions on a Linux system are normally set to 755 for folders and 644 for files. It is recommended to keep these permissions in use for the NTFS partition as well if you use the partition on a regular basis. The following example assigns the above permissions to a normal user: /dev/NTFS-partition  /mnt/windows  ntfs-3g uid=userid,gid=groupid,dmask=022,fmask=133 0 0

Comment: Standard linux driver(in the terminal: sudo modinfo ntfs) does not know how to write to NTFS volumes! If you want to read-write, then use NTFS-3G(sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g). Xubuntu has NTFS-3G and FUSE installed by default. Thunar with user rights mounts and unmounts ntfs partitions. For automounting sudo su in the terminal:lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID next mousepad /etc/fstab and add UUID=(UUID partition) /media/user/(UUID or LABEL) ntfs-3g defaults,noatime,nodev,nosuid,locale=(in the terminal locale) 0 0

Comment: Thanks for your tips. After 1 more days of searching, I can confirm that everything works normally in Thunar, just not in terminal (Kitty in my case). NTFS-3G is installed by default. I think I have to dig deep to understand what `ntfsusermap` does.