# permission denied on ubuntu ( ubuntu and windows 10 dual boot system on a M.2 NVME ssd and another harddrive used for storage)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, ssd, gcc

I have a 250GB m.2 nvme ssd and a 1TB hdd. I boot ubuntu and windows on my ssd by creating 2 partition and I use my hdd for storage only.
I recently install gcc on my ubuntu. but can't run c++ file on ubuntu which is located on my hdd.

it says permission denied. but on windows I can access and run the same file. what should I need to change to run the c/c++ file on ubuntu?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "run c++ file" exactly? Are you referring to the source code file itself, or are you compiling an executable program and attempting to run that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)