# CIFS mount through fstab not mounting at boot

Tags: fstab, automount

I have a CIFS share on my NAS that I want to have mounted at boot - it's used by my MythTV server as the main media store. I added an entry into `fstab` to have it mount but it doesn't.  It appears that, after looking through my system logs, `fstab` is being read before my network interfaces are coming online. Is there any edit I can make to the `fstab` entry that would alter this?

The `fstab` entry for mounting the share is:

```
\\192.168.0.26\mythtv\media  /media/mybooklive  cifs  username=user,password=pass,umask=002,uid=136,gid=144,iocharset=utf8   0       0
```

It mounts fine after boot when I issue `sudo mount -a` and there are no other issues with it.

Thanks!

Comment: If the server is running Ubuntu, it is likely you need a / rather then a \ - "//192.168.0.26/mythtv/media " See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: @bodhi.zazen It may have had the / when I entered it, but it now reads out with the \

Comment: Check the syntax ( / vs \ ) in fstab

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I'm pretty sure that the wiki article is what I followed when setting it up. I'll check syntax later when I get time to sit with my server.

Comment: After reading your question again, I think you need to follow djmadscribbler's advice.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Please convert your comment to an answer - changing the \ to / solved it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a syntax error, I think you need a "/" rather then a "\", like this

```
//192.168.0.26/mythtv/media  /media/mybooklive  cifs  username=user,password=pass,_netdev,umask=002,uid=136,gid=144,iocharset=utf8  0 0
```

See : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently for additional information.

Answer (score 46):

If `_netdev` doesn't work, try this option instead:

```
x-systemd.automount
```

It works by mounting the drive at first access.

To test the automount, unmount your share if it's currently mounted:

```
sudo umount /media/mybooklive
```

And then restart the `remote-fs` systemd unit:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
```

Comment: thank you, this worked for me in 18.04 LTS

Comment: _netdev wasn't working on 18.04, this worked perfectly :)

Comment: Works in Raspbian 10

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer for Ubuntu 20.04 as well

Comment: Excellent! This is the only thing that worked my Mybooklive to mount on boot. Also had to add `vers=1.0` as an option.

Comment: Works in Raspbian 11

Answer (score 39):

Have you tried adding the option `_netdev` to your `fstab` entry? You would add it with the other options in your string like so

```
//192.168.0.26/mythtv/media  /media/mybooklive  cifs  username=user,password=pass,_netdev,umask=002,uid=136,gid=144,iocharset=utf8   0       0
```

`_netdev` is supposed to delay the mount until after the network connects.

Comment: Can you add context to where that would be placed in the `fstab` line? With that, and a period where I can reboot the server when it's not being used, I will give it a try. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Turns out bodhi.zazen had the right track with his comment. I did give you an upvote for your help. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 12.04 but not in Ubuntu 16.04.  Has this changed in the latest version?

Comment: same here, not working in 16.04

Comment: Note: I think _netdev actually works in 16.04, however credentials=/home/user/.smbcreds does no longer works.  At least for me when I use user=, pass=, _netdev it works, when I use credentials=,_netdev it does not.  Both work via sudo mount-a from the command line after booting.

Comment: I actually think this might have more to do with the permission changes that were made to the media folder. At some point, Ubuntu started mounting things to /media/username/folder name rather than /media/folder name. If don't mount to the "username" location then you have to have sudo level permissions for access. If you change your path to use the /media/username path I think it should still work.

Comment: _netdev - Only valid with fstype nfs

Comment: This worked, but only after I figured out that my network path also wasn't resolving properly on my local network. I had to add a domain suffix. Probably a peculiarity of my PFSense box. I was trying to mount //freenas/x/y, but my dns resolver wanted to see //freenas.pflan/x/y.

Answer (score 17):

I am using the Raspbian-Stretch build dated 2017-09-07 and experienced the same issue. However, I was able to overcome this by going into raspi-config and under the Boot Options menu, I enabled the "Wait for network at boot" option.

Comment: This is actually VERY helpful, i had problems that even if boot said everything OK it did just not mounted it or display folders

Comment: Thanks! That was it. This must be #1 reason for fstab entries not loading or raspberries as such option is turned off by default. Cheers.

Comment: This does a great job of filling in for the "_netdev" argument, which ONLY works for NFS shares.

Answer (score 6):

- Using forward slashes (/) did NOT fix it for me.
- Also, adding the option `_netdev` to my `/etc/fstab` entry did NOT fix it for me.

What I have done to fix this problem (on my Pi3) is modify `/etc/rc.local` to sleep 20 seconds (by calling `sleep 20`) and then call `mount -a`. This way, even though the network is NOT connected yet when the system first reads the `fstab` file, so the mount fails then, I force the system to wait 20 seconds here (giving the network time to connect) then I force it to call `mount -a` again to mount all drives in the `fstab` file.

Here is what my `/etc/rc.local` file now looks like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
# GS notes: a *minimum* of `sleep 10` is required for the mount below to
# work on the Pi 3; it failed with `sleep 5`, but worked with `sleep 10`,
# `sleep 15`, and `sleep 30`
sleep 20
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
  mount -a #GS: mount all drives in /etc/fstab
fi

exit 0
```

Done! It now works perfectly for me!

References:

1. [my answer] https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/63690/49091
2. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md
3. http://elinux.org/RPi_Email_IP_On_Boot_Debian - they have a similar `rc.local` file with a comment in it that says:

   ```bsh
   # Print the IP address if it doesn't work ad sleep 30 before all your code
   ```

English grammar follow-up question I had regarding an edit to my answer:

1. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/568348/need-help-identifying-if-this-is-1-grammatically-correct-and-2-an-infinitive

Comment: Are you connecting via wifi?

Comment: Yes, I'm using WiFi instead of ethernet.

Comment: That's indeed very strange, but probably not related to my issue. I have three network drives I'm trying to connect through an ethernet cable - no wifi. One of the drives' names has a special character in it, and that causes it to not be connected after a fresh boot. Executing `sudo mount -a` solves the issue, but I'm curious why it doesn't work while booting up. I'll try your solution and see if that helps.

Comment: You wrote "What I have done to fix this problem (on my Pi3) is **modify** /etc/rc.local to sleep". The use of 'modify' here is good correct English. To use 'modifying' would be wrong. Pseudo-cleft sentences (also called wh-clefts) are similar in function to cleft sentences, but they are formed with the pronoun what (= the thing(s) that/which). The emphasis in a pseudo-cleft sentence is on the phrase after the what-clause + be: In the past simple and present perfect, we can use the following pattern What I have done is (to) write a letter to the editor.

Answer (score 3):

The failsafe method, always remember these 3 altogether:

- `noauto`
- `x-systemd.automount`
- `_netdev`

Always works.

Method from [How to auto mount using sshfs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43363/how-to-auto-mount-using-sshfs/1242516#1242516), which I'm quoting below:

> I am adding an `fstab` method, since no one talks about it in this page. If you don't want hacks and use the builtin advanced mounting features, you need to use `/etc/fstab` and never look back.
>
> ```
> user@host:/remote/folder /mount/point  fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,IdentityFile=/home/name/.ssh/id_rsa, allow_other,reconnect 0 0
> ```
>
> - `noauto` will stop the no-brainer actions like forcibly mounting whatsoever at booting regardless if the network is up or not.
> - `x-systemd.automount` is the smart daemon that knows when to mount.
> - The `_netdev` tag will also identify that it uses network devices, thus it will wait until the network is up.

Comment: it has not work in my 20.04LTS machine, there has to be some more secret ingredients.

Comment: Worked great for me on Debian 11 (Bullseye) for a CIFS mount. Thanks!