# mount drive at boot attached to asus wireless router

Tags: fstab

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.10.

Previously, I had Ubuntu 15.04.  In 15.04, I had this entry in my fstab file to mount an external hard drive that is attached to my wireless router:

//rt-ac87r-8b48/My_Book /media/rt-ac87r-8b48 cifs user,guest,uid=1000,gid=users,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,_netdev,noperm 0 0

In 15.04, this worked great - at boot, the drive mounted.

In 15.10, with the exact same fstab file, I get no error messages, but this drive does NOT mount at boot.  I have to manually mount it (which works fine).

I'm at a loss as to what to look at next to figure out why this will not work.  I have the cifs tools installed in 15.10 (as they were in 15.04).

Comment: I had to add the option vers=1.0 for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This row from fstab works fine on my kubuntu 15.10

```
//192.168.1.1/usbRouter /home/user/myshare cifs username=<yourusername>,password=<yourpwd> 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `_netdev` stopped working in a lot of Debian distros around this time. I had the same problem but using `x-systemd.automount` instead, as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/823022/817914), fixed it for me.

Your fstab entry should look like

```
//rt-ac87r-8b48/My_Book /media/rt-ac87r-8b48 cifs user,guest,uid=1000,gid=users,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,x-systemd.automount,noperm 0 0
```