# how can I get my fstab mounts working if they won't mount on bootup?

Tags: boot, 16.04, samba, fstab, cifs

[CIFS mount through fstab not mounting at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399643/cifs-mount-through-fstab-not-mounting-at-boot)

The suggested answers (a typo in fstab; _netdev) have no effect. However when I mount them with `sudo mount -a` there are no issues and they are mounted.

Here's the first entry. The other two are nearly identical, just a different path on each side of the connection.

```
# added line break for readability 
//192.168.1.9/video/cartoons /media/saturn-cartoons 
cifs credentials=/home/media/.smbcredentials,_netdev,
iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Comment: I got mine to mount with this `credentials=/home/media/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0` not sure the other stuff in the line is needed and may not be enabled correctly .. I really don't know much about it but I know what is working for me :D