# how can I force a mount -a to run after the system boots up?

Tags: boot, networking, mount, samba, fstab

Media server running Ubuntu 16.04 and Kodi. Synology NAS in the next room contains all the media.

[how can I get my fstab mounts working if they won't mount on bootup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776149/how-can-i-get-my-fstab-mounts-working-if-they-wont-mount-on-bootup) -- tried switching to username/password instead of .smbcredentials, no change.

Tried adding `_netdev`, no change.

I've tried fixing my `/etc/fstab` and it's just not working. I'm not sure what the problem is, but I cannot get my NAS folders to mount that way. Posted here, posted on ubuntuforums, no go (didn't get any answers in either one). Every time I reboot I have to `ssh` in to the box to get my media folders back.

So, I thought I'd take a different approach. I'm assuming there is some issue with my NAS or network that makes mounting at boot via `fstab` to not work. I don't know.

Since I know that my folders will mount with `sudo mount -a`, how can I run that command at boot time after everything else (network especially) is done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to add your command at startup would be to add it as a `cron` job.

Add your command to the `root` `cron` by typing in the following line in a terminal window:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

then at the bottom of the `cron` add a line that reads like this:

```
@reboot /bin/mount -a
```

or if you want to add a delay of like 10 seconds to it:

```
@reboot /bin/bash -c 'sleep 10 && /bin/mount -a'
```

that should tell it to run the `mount -a` command as `root` at boot up time.

Or, you could add it to your system wide crontab by editing the following file:

```
/etc/crontab
```

and adding the following line:

```
@reboot root /bin/bash -c 'sleep 10 && /bin/mount -a'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/335615/does-ubuntu-support-reboot-in-crontab -- had to add "root" before /bin/bash. Still doesn't work though. They mount fine with sudo mount but `@reboot root /bin/bash -c 'sleep 10 && /sbin/mount -a'` doesn't do anything. Is it the /sbin that's the problem? I got an error with /bin

Comment: Oh wait it worked **but** using `sudo crontab -e` seems to open the wrong crontab. I did `sudo vi crontab` and it worked

Comment: @jcollum That is interesting, but glad you got it working.    =)

Comment: @jcollum I am going to add that to my answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's trying to mount your share before the network is ready.

In this case, you should add `_netdev` option in your /etc/fstab.

Example :

```
//server/share /mountpoint  cifs username=xx,password=yy,_netdev 0 0
```

This forces the OS to wait for the network to be ready before trying to mount this mountpoint.

Comment: _netdev - sorry, I forgot to mention that I tried that.