# 22.04 is not reconnecting to Windows shares after reboot, until sudo mount -a

Tags: 22.04, fstab, cifs

Just as the title says, I have configured the fstab file properly and it reads it and connects when I use the "sudo mount -a" command yet after rebooting and signing in it does not reconnect until I manually issue that command again.

Right now, the connect line looks essentially like this:

```
//server/path /mnt/point cifs credentials=/etc/credentialfile 0 0
```

I have also tried:

```
//server/path /mnt/point cifs credentials=/etc/credentialfile,_netdev 0 0
//server/path /mnt/point cifs credentials=/etc/credentialfile,uid=1000_netdev 0 0
```

All of them work perfect when doing mount -a but then do not reconnect after a reboot.

What am I missing?

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe the NIC is not yet acivated at the time of mounting FSs from FStab. Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/399643/cifs-mount-through-fstab-not-mounting-at-boot

Comment: Adding "x-systemd.automount" does seem to have worked, even though "_netdev" did not. Type this up as an answer, and I will accept it. Although will probably be tomorrow before I do.  It's late.

Comment: It is not my answer :-) Better upvote the answer in the link I sent.

Comment: Don't have the rep yet to up-vote, but thanks anyway.

Comment: You can upvote, there's no minimum rep required for that. There is for downvoting.

Comment: @ChanganAuto You actually need 15 rep to Up-vote. I just tried it again on the correct answer on the other question and I get this as a popup:

"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."